# Restate values using forward fill and groupby with condition (reduce value by 1 at each row)

Tags: python

I have 2 columns: **x** and **y**. I want to restate the values of **y** and make it continuous like 10,9,8,7,6...0 so if there are missing values in **y** it should be filled by = (previous value - 1) same case if there is smaller value then expected. and another condition is, it should be **group by** column **x**.

**columns I have:** 'x', 'y'

**column I want:** 'desire_output'

you can look at the table below to have a better understanding.

```
x   y   desire_output
1   10  10
1   9   9
1   NaN 8
1   NaN 7
1   6   6
1   5   5
1   4   4
1   3   3
1   2   2
1   1   1
1   0   0
1   4   4
1   0   3
1   0   2
1   1   1
2   8   8
2   6   7
2   3   6
2   5   5
2   4   4
2   3   3
```

Currently, I have this code which uses a loop. please let me know if anyone has a better way or an efficient way to solve this problem.

> `def update_frame(df):
>       sd = {"last_expected": None}
>       def apply_logic(row):
>           last_row_id = row.name - 1
>           if row.name == 0:
>               sd['last_expected'] = row["y"]
>               return sd['last_expected']
>           last_row = df.iloc[[last_row_id]].iloc[0].to_dict()
>           sd['last_expected'] = max(sd['last_expected'] - 1, row['y']) if last_row['x'] == row['x'] else row['y']
>           return sd['last_expected']
>       return apply_logic
>   df.apply(update_frame(daily_bal), axis = 1)`

Comment: This was my first question on stack overflow. I am still learning, thanks for pointing it out. let me know if it's still not clear to you.

Comment: Just to be clear... do you want to increment the `group` value each time the count down in `desire_output is broken?

Comment: Your question is not clear. I changed the variable names to be more clear. I don't want to change the value of x and y. I want to group by on x and restate the value of y. and there is no increment, I want to reduce the value by one.

Comment: Ah so is the other way around. I think I got it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to group over the `x` column and then starting from the first value in `y` to count down.

And in case when counting down you reach negative values, reset the counter to the corresponding `y` value.

This is what the code below does:

```
out = df.groupby('x').apply(lambda dd : pd.Series(range(int(dd['y'].iloc[0]), int(dd['y'].iloc[0]) - len(dd), -1)))
df['desired_output'] = out.reset_index(drop=True)

while (df['desired_output'] < 0).any():
    corr = df.groupby('x').apply(lambda dd : (dd['y'] +1).where(dd['desired_output'].eq(-1), 0).cumsum())
    df['correcting'] = corr.reset_index(drop=True).astype(int)
    df['desired_output'] = df['correcting'] + df['desired_output']

df.drop('correcting', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The `while` loop allows to perform the same operation until there are no more negative values in `'desired_output'` column, adding each time the correct value to set the first negative number (`-1`) to the value in `y`.

Assuming `df` is the sample dataframe you posted, the final result is:

```
    x     y  desired_output
0   1  10.0              10
1   1   9.0               9
2   1   NaN               8
3   1   NaN               7
4   1   6.0               6
5   1   5.0               5
6   1   4.0               4
7   1   3.0               3
8   1   2.0               2
9   1   1.0               1
10  1   0.0               0
11  1   4.0               4
12  1   0.0               3
13  1   0.0               2
14  1   1.0               1
15  2   8.0               8
16  2   6.0               7
17  2   3.0               6
18  2   5.0               5
19  2   4.0               4
20  2   3.0               3
```

The assumption here is that `x` is monothonic (no sparsed values) and that in the row where `x` increases, `y` is not `NaN`, like shown by your example. Also, `y` should not be `NaN` when the count down is `-1`.

Comment: thanks for the solution but it doesn't solve my main problem. and sorry for not been clear in the first place. I have made one more change to the example I have given.If It completes the full cycle 5,4,3,2,1,0 and after that, if there there is a new number then we need to start it again.

Comment: hi Valentio sorry for the late reply. so your code solves the problem but it's not that efficient. my dataset is really big and the code I have takes less time than yours. I was looking for a more efficient way to solve this problem. I have edited my question and added the code I have currently. Have a look and see if you can think of any more more efficient way than this.