# off set date based on another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

```
columnx      columny    results
2019-02-15      2        2019-04-15
2019-05-08      1        2019-06-08
```

It should not change the days of the month like 15 should be 15 and 8 should be 8. In case of 31 to 30 and vice versa, it's okay. Most Importantly I don't wanna use .apply(). Thanks!

Comment: If you have a relatively small number of unique offsets, you can do something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174267/computing-age-from-to-timedelta-is-weird-and-dateoffset-is-not-scalable-over-a just use `months=` instead of years. Is that viable in this case?

Comment: Great Man, Impressive! that is an amazing solution. It is not any complex method but it's very logical. Thanks, it works for me.

Comment: @ALollz Hi, I have a question unsolved would you mind also looking into it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57045870/restate-values-using-forward-fill-and-groupby-with-condition-reduce-value-by-1?noredirect=1#comment100713418_57045870

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it.
Pls check that you have datetime format in your columnx and then run below.

EDIT

```
df["results"]=df["columnx"]+ df['columny'].astype('timedelta64[M]'))
```

Comment: I really appreciate, you taking the time and try to help. But to_timedelta counts days and minutes so let's say if the date is 2016-11-15 and you add pd.to_timedelta(2,"M") it will give you 2016-11-14 20:00:00, in that case, it will change the date 15 to 14 which is the restriction. again if you use 4 (including the month of Feb) it will change the date 2017-03-16 17:56:24 as there are 2 days less in Feb. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Pls recheck if this would do?